Cartoon with a muscular main character who's wearing sunglasses
I'm looking for a cartoon show in which the main character

is a muscular male,
has ginger/yellow afro,
is wearing sunglasses,
has an absurd name ("bon pon", "pon pon", or something like that),
and is a bodyguard/caretaker.

The show takes place in a surrealistic world.

Would it be Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo?


Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo (ボボボーボ・ボーボボ Bobobōbo Bōbobo?), or "Bobobo" as he is often called, is the main protagonist and title character. Bobobo is an eccentric man with bodybuilder sized muscles and a giant yellow afro. He fights the forces of evil using his nose hair calling it his "Fist of the Nose Hair" and "Snot Fo-You" technique. He is 27 years old. It is unclear what race he is, or if he is even human. It was never fully explained in the show. His father was a hair ball like creature. His birthday differs between the manga and the anime; the manga lists his birthday as April 1, while the anime claims his birthday to be March 14. His most striking features are his large blond afro and sunglasses. Bo-bobo's full name written in kanji is "母母母ー母・母ー母母". Bo-Bobo closely resembles the Japanese stereotype of an American from the 70's era.
Source: List of Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo characters @ Wikipedia



Could it by any chance be Johnny Bravo?
The name doesn't really match with what you think it is, and I have no idea what his profession is, but the visual description seems to be spot on.


Beat me by 13 minutes.

I think that Johnny has no profession. It'd be out of the character. However, I think he lives in our everyday world, and not some "surrealistic" one.

@VedranŠego Yeah, haven't seen an episode in ages, but he does seem to do very little... However, it's not impossible that he do have some sort of job, though, even if he might not end up doing it very well. If he does have one, bodyguard/caretaker seems like the kind of thing someone would hire him for. And when it comes to the world he lives in, most cartoons are surrealistic in one way or the other, so I didn't read too much into it.

@VedranŠego Your answer do seem like a better match, though. So +1 for that
